# Is this a trap?

Tags: learning

So I have a game board as follows where my opponent moved their bishop to be openly captured by my queen.

[image]

Is there any reason for me to not take the bishop? I can’t foresee any immediate counter moves but I don’t know if there is a trap a few moves ahead.

[image]

Comment: Asking this question here is just throwing away valuable time. Please consider feeding the position to a chess engine.

Comment: @WaisKamal , feel free to send me the chess engine. Thank you for your input.

Comment: It depends on your operating system. You can download Stockfish for any operating system [here](https://stockfishchess.org).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a trap, just a blunder. There's no way for White to take advantage of your slightly exposed queen or the unprotected knight on d4.

Comment: All answers are helpful +1, but you answered first. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5):

Imagine the position with the move `Qxg5` already played. Is there anything White can do to you that you would not like?

Look for checks, captures and threats. The only check is `Bb5+`, which can be met by `...Nxb5`, so no need to worry about that. White doesn't really have any dangerous captures or threats either, since if anything you can take on g2 next.

Since there's no reason not the take the bishop, take it and be a piece up!

Answer (score 4):

No traps here, just a free piece. I'm guessing your opponent missed your Queen could take the Bishop.

A good way to figure out if something is a trap is to ask "What will have changed if my Queen is on g5 instead of d8"? Is there some kind of tactic against the Queen on that square (perhaps a discovered attack on it)? Was the Queen doing something important on d8 that it will not do anymore (such as defending the c7-pawn)?

The answers to both of these questions is no -- White has no tactics against a Queen on g5, and there is no way for White to take advantage of the Queen being missed on d8.